# How to pass excel file data from Angular 5 to .Net core web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, angular5, asp.net-core-webapi

I am developing Angular application, In this application user will upload excel file and then i want to do calculation based on data in file and insert into SQL table . Now problem is how can i pass excel data from my Angular application to Web API (may be POST method)

Comment: "Write my program for me," is not a valid Stack Overflow question.

Comment: At the very least you should show us what you've already tried. You should ask focused questions about specific programming problems you're having.